# How can I not agressively let my friend know I don't want to be hugged/touched?

Tags: friends, boundaries

I have a friend with whom I was very, very close in the past. We would hug often (as a greeting/goodbye, but those kinds of long hugs); we would be sitting together and it would happen that our legs/arms would touch (he takes a lot of space as a tal, athletic guy) and that would be the norm.

We have since had a falling out of sorts. Not an agressive one, but I definitely feel differently about our friendship, and have told him so. However, he keeps coming for a hug everytime we see each other; but I don't want to hug him (although I also don't want to hurt his feelings...) so I kind of just let myself be (awkwardly) hugged. Same goes for casual touch; I don't want him leaning against me so I duck out, or just shift so our bodies are as far away as possible, and it is awkward, and stressful for me.

**What are some polite, friendly ways to (openly) convey that I want this kind of physical interaction to stop?**

Comment: How does he identify you?  Male of female?

Comment: @Johns-305 I am a female and he is a male.

Comment: Telling someone, even very nicely, that you don't wish to hug then anymore can be hurtful, and that person might react negatively. Are you ready to alter the relationship again ? Or is preserving the friendship a top priority ?

Comment: @MlleMei preserving the relationship is a goal, but not at all costs. That is, if I cannot be comfortable, then I would have to stay away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decline a hug without offending?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/how-can-i-decline-a-hug-without-offending) - especially given the past history of hugging. For a perspective from the other side, see [How to find out, if it is ok to hug](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20395/how-to-find-out-if-it-is-ok-to-hug-opposite-sex)